# Bessel Integration in matlab

Tags: integration, summation, matlab, bessel-functions

I was trying to do integral in matlab with below equation. Could anyone help me please to do with Riemann sum approach in matlab? Thanks in advance!!

$$\int_0^\infty{{e}}^{-{k^2}/{4}} J_0(k)k{d} k$$

Comment: this is not equation. did you miss something?

Comment: Thanks a lot Nosrati! I removed some constant parameters.

Answer (score 3):

No need for Riemann sums. By the very definition of $J_0$,

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2/4}xJ_0(x)\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n n!^2}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{2n+1} e^{-x^2/4}\,dx}_{2\cdot 4^n\cdot n!}=2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=\color{red}{\frac{2}{e}}. $$

Comment: Wow that was short. Can you please explain or point to reference on how one knows / derives the integral which becomes $2\cdot 2^{2n}\cdot n!$ ?

Comment: @mathreadler: $\int_{0}^{+\infty} z^n e^{-z}\,dz = n!$.

Comment: Ah, wait it's gamma function isn't it? I didn't see it first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a closed form (compact form) solution to this integration in the Table of Integrals 7E, Eq 6.631.1 as $$\int_0^{\infty}x^{\mu}e^{-\alpha x^2}\,J_v(\beta\,x)\,dx = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}v+\frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\beta\,\alpha^{\frac{1}{2}\mu}\Gamma\left(v+1\right)}\exp\left(-\frac{\beta^2}{8\alpha}\right)\,M_{\frac{1}{2}\mu,\,\frac{1}{2}v}\left(\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\right)$$

where $\Gamma(.)$ is the Gamma function, and $M_{\mu,v}(.)$ is the Whittaker function.

If you still want to do numerically

1- define the function $$f(k)=ke^{-k^2/4}J_0(k)$$.

2- Define the step size, e.g., `dk = 0.01`.

3- Initialize a variable `total = 0`.

4- loop over `k` from `0` to some upper bound with an increment size `dk`.

5- for each value of `k` add to `total` the value `f(k)`.

6- At the end of the `for` loop, compare the result with the analytical solution to make sure your work is correct.

Comment: Your initial integral lacks an $x$ term. The actual outcome does not involve $I_0(1/2)$ but just $e^{-1}$.

Comment: Right, I treated `k` as a constant. I will edit my answer. Thanks